# ActiveRecord searching by pseudo attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

On my model I have the method

```
def complete?
    self.address_id && self.user_id && self.location
end
```

Is it possible to do a search with activerecord for records where this is true or will I have to just check all of these columns are not nil in each lookup?

Comment: You don't need `self.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the way to do this is to create a scope for the model:

```
scope :complete, -> { where.not(address_id: nil, user_id: nil, location_id: nil)}
```

And then search with `Model.complete`